# AttributeError: DescribeData: Method FIDSet does not exist error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I am writing an add-in that in one step requires to find all layers that have selections. To achieve that I am using `FIDSet` property of `Describe` object. Unfortunately, I get an error: "AttributeError: DescribeData: Method FIDSet does not exist" (why "method" anyway?). While I perform test like this, in Python window in ArcMap:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("O_PODST")
desc.FIDSet()
```

Everything works fine, but while using my add-in I get this error. 
How to make it work? 
Here is my code:

```
class ShowParcLU(object):
    """Implementation for Okienko_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

        if arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd, "PARC_LU"):
            layers_with_selections = []

            for i in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
                if len([int(fid) for fid in arcpy.Describe(i).FIDSet.split(";") if fid != '']) > 0:
                    layers_with_selections.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in layers present in project. One of them was a Raster layer and obviously Describe object created on Raster layer doesn't have FIDset property. I should put an additional If statement in loop over layers preventing this error.

```
            for i in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
                if i.isFeatureLayer:
                    if arcpy.Describe(i).FIDSet:
                        layers_with_selections.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

`FIDSet` is a `Describe` property of a feature layer. `dataSource` will return the full path to a layer's data source. In your code, you want to reference the layer, not its data source, so remove `dataSource`.

```
if len([int(fid) for fid in arcpy.Describe(i).FIDSet.split(";") if fid != '']) > 0:
```

FYI, cleaner code to get what you're after (checking for selection):

```
if arcpy.Describe(i).FIDSet:
```

Comment: You are right, I should reference Layer. I probably even have tried that before... Anyway it is still not working... "RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type". However, I tested this add-in in ArcMap 10.3 and it works fine! But I need it working also on 10.2.

Comment: OK, so it wasn' t about ArcMap version but about the layers in project...